# How to deny script execution in all sub-directories?

Tags: shell, nginx, webserver

I want nginx to deny users who have folders inside /webroot/uploads

e.g.

```
/webroot/uploads/user1
/webroot/uploads/user2
/webroot/uploads/user999
```

to execute any shell script or binary (php, pl, py).

The malicious codes are often hidden in jpg or gif files. like badfile.php.jpg

I also see malacious binary files being uploaded to the folder.

Here my preliminary rules:

```
location ~ /webroot/uploads/(.+)\.php$ {
 deny all;
}

location ~ /webroot/uploads/(.+)\.pl$ {
 deny all;
}
```

But I am not sure it is robust enough. So I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

nginx doesn't have CGI support exactly for this reason - by default, people can't upload random scripts or executables and then run them.

If you have a FastCGI bridge which executes files, check its configuration and whether you can deny the webroot/uploads directory.

You could also force uploaded files to not have the execute bit set, though (depending on who is running the files, see below) that may not help. For details, use something like `upload_store_access user:rw` (see the [HttpUploadModule documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule#upload_store_access) for details).

One last point is a vulnerability by misconfiguration, through which someone could have random files (not ending in `.php`) be executed by the PHP handler. Follow [this article](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/) for the details and correct configuration.